# set names utf8 php PDO

Tags: mysql, set, names

I need a small help to add "set names utf8" to this code. 
php version is 5.6.3

```
# global variables
$host='localhost'; 
$mySqlUser='root';       
$mySqlPassword='';      
$mySqlDatabase='loginProject';      

try{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$mySqlDatabase;host=$host;",$mySqlUser,$mySqlPassword,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));          
}catch(PDOException $ex){
    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Database connection failed')));   
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: also you should add php tag for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Last parameter of `PDO` constructor gets `$option` as array so you can add what you want to this array.

Your solution is

```
    $db = new PDO(
    "mysql:dbname=$mySqlDatabase;host=$host;",
    $mySqlUser,
    $mySqlPassword,
    array(
         PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
    )
);
```

[PHP: PDO::_construct doc](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)